# Rotation of LinearLayout makes it cut off

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Trying to rotate my LinearLayout for about 270deg, but view get's cut off.

```
layout.rotation = 270f
```

Also tried to set `layerType` but doesn't work also

```
layout.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
```

Did i miss something? 
How do i can rotate it properly?

[image: After rotation in android studio editor]

Comment: have you tried `android:clipChildren="false"` on its parent?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yep, doesn't work :(

Comment: Do you have a fixed width or height for the LinearLayout?

Comment: @MatPag no, it’s set to WRAP_CONTENT (width and height)